# HTTP Response logging if using Ion

Tags: android, android-ion

We can set logging if we use Ion to make HTTP connection to server as below

```
Ion.getDefault(getContext()).configure().setLogging("MyLogs", Log.DEBUG);
```

But we can't see the HTTP response from server from log that generated.

How to see HTTP response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ion does not put the response body into the logs, as the body may be enormous, binary, etc.
If you want to log the body, do so yourself in the setCallback.

Comment: I think logging the http response is useful to debug the application. We can see all http request and http response in logging if we use Retrofit :)

Comment: I just added support for Facebook's Stetho last week, which lets you view all requests/responses in the Chrome debugger console. This may be what you want. I'll document it and roll it out soon.

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/tree/master/AndroidAsyncStetho/src/com/koushikdutta/async/stetho